# How to give Multiple Projections in MongoDB java using Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

i have three documents

```
{ "_id" : 3, "quizzes" : [ 4, 5, 5 ], "labs" : [ 6, 5 ], "final" : 78, "midterm" : 70 }
{ "_id" : 2, "quizzes" : [ 9, 10 ], "labs" : [ 8, 8 ], "final" : 95, "midterm" : 80 }
{ "_id" : 1, "quizzes" : [ 10, 6, 7 ], "labs" : [ 5, 8 ], "final" : 80, "midterm" : 75, "extraMarks" : 10 }
```

I have to query exam total fields as sum of final +midterm+extramarks.
The query is as follows:
**Query1:**

```
  db.students.aggregate([ { "$project": { "final": 1, "midterm": 1, "examTotal": { "$add": [ "$final", "$midterm", { "$ifNull": [ "$extraMarks", 10 ] } ] } } } ])
```

But along with this i need to get this only for people whose id is greater than equal to 1 and less than equal to 2

So i have modified the code to the following:
**Query2:**

```
 db.students.aggregate([ { $match: { $and: [ { _id: { $gte: 1, $lte: 2 } }]}}, { "$project": { "final": 1, "midterm": 1, "examTotal": { "$add": [ "$final", "$midterm", { "$ifNull": [ "$extraMarks", 10 ] } ] } } } ])
```

How to convert this code to Java code for query 1 i made the code and is working? How to add match stage in the existing code which is as follows:

```
BsonArray fields=new BsonArray();
            BsonArray defaultValue1=new BsonArray();
            defaultValue1.add(new BsonString("$extraMarks"));
            defaultValue1.add(new BsonDouble(0d));          
            BsonDocument ifNullProjection=new BsonDocument();
            ifNullProjection.put("$ifNull",defaultValue1);
            fields.add(new BsonString("$final"));
            fields.add("$midterm");
            fields.add(ifNullProjection);
            BsonDocument addObject=new BsonDocument();
            addObject.append("$add", fields);
            BsonDocument valueTobeUpdate=new BsonDocument();
            valueTobeUpdate.append("sum", addObject);
            BsonDocument mainProjection=new BsonDocument();
            mainProjection.append("$project", valueTobeUpdate);
            List<BsonDocument> pipeline=new ArrayList<BsonDocument>();
            pipeline.add(mainProjection);
            AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = refCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

**How to add $match operator to the code shown above?Any suggestions?**

Comment: Why don't you `pipeline.add` the match stage, just like you added the projection stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator in the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline is not really necessary since you can implicitly do an AND operation by just specifying a comma separated list of expressions.

The aggregation pipeline can be restructured to :

**Mongo shell:**

---

```
/*
    MONGO SHELL: 
    var pipeline = [ 
        { 
            "$match": { "_id": { "$gte": 1, "$lte": 2 } } // or  "$match": { "_id": { "$in": [1,2] } }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project": { 
                "final": 1, 
                "midterm": 1, 
                "examTotal": { 
                    "$add": [ "$final", "$midterm", { "$ifNull": [ "$extraMarks", 10 ] } ] 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    ];
    db.students.aggregate(pipeline);

*/
```

---

**Java implementation:**

```
public class JavaAggregation {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException {

        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient();
        DB db = mongo.getDB("test");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("students");

        // create the pipeline operations, first with the $match
        DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
                            new BasicDBObject("_id",
                                new BasicDBObject("$gte", 1).append("$lt", 2)
                            )
                        );

        // build the $project operations
        BasicDBList coalesce = new BasicDBList();
        coalesce.add("$extraMarks");
        coalesce.add(10)
        DBObject ifNullClause = new BasicDBObject("$ifNull", coalesce);  

        BasicDBList addition = new BasicDBList();
        addition.add("$final");
        addition.add("$midterm");
        addition.add(ifNullClause);

        DBObject examTotal = new BasicDBObject("$add", addition);

        DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("final", 1);
        fields.put("midterm", 1);
        fields.put("examTotal", examTotal);

        DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
        List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, project);

        AggregationOutput output = coll.aggregate(pipeline);

        for (DBObject result : output.results()) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```